# Electron-React-Material UI Color Property

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Just installed electron an react with the material ui. on my app-bar component im using the color property, but when loading in a color its removing all color and making it white. ive copied it from the docs so not sure what im missing, my code it below.

first imported the color

```
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import red from '@material-ui/core/colors/red';
import red from '@material-ui/core/colors/red';
```

setup a const value

```
const primary = red[500]; // #F44336
```

applied it to the AppBar component

```
<AppBar position="static" color={primary}>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Electron-React-Material UI combo, and coloring works fine for me.

You are applying '#F44336' to color property and AppBar Component expects one of the values: 'inherit' || 'primary' || 'secondary' || 'default'. You can check out more on documentation for Material UI AppBar: https://material-ui.com/api/app-bar/, but the information you need is:

> Name: color
>
> Type: enum: 'inherit' |  'primary' |  'secondary' |  'default'
>
> Default: 'primary' - The color of the component.
>
> Description - It supports those theme colors that make sense for this component.

Also, since you applied unexpected value ('#F44336'), the color fallback should be "default" which is white, you can see how that looks in the first example: https://material-ui.com/demos/app-bar/. And if you check out code in the second example you can see how to append styles to Material UI Component (in this case AppBar) - with "withStyles". So if you need a different color of your AppBar then primary/secondary/default colors defined in your theme, you can always (force) change it in the styles.

I don't know how familiar are you with Material UI, but you can define a primary color for the entire application in "MUITheme" file. Then you will be able to use it like this:

```
<AppBar position='static' color='primary'>
```

(Note that I am applying string, not variable primary :) ).

Also here is an example you might consider handy:

App.js file wrapped with MuiThemeProvider and custom theme:

```
App.js

import MainTheme from './MainTheme';
.
.
.
class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={MainTheme}>
        <AppBar position='static' color='primary' />
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}
```

And the custom theme file which has a primary, secondary and error colors defined:

```
MainTheme.js

import { createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';
import { teal, blueGrey, red } from 'material-ui/colors';

const MainTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: teal,
    secondary: blueGrey,
    error: { main: red[ 500 ] },
  },
});

export default MainTheme;
```

After you define the primary color you can use it with color='primary', and it should work in almost every Material UI Component.

I hope this helps! :)